# creating list of lists of premutations without changing certain values in the orginal list

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, backtracking, game-theory

im trying to write a nonogram program and having a trouble with understanding the following:
I'm trying to create a nested list using recursion from the following parameters:

- `row`: a list made of 1, 0 or -1, eg. [0,-1,-1,1]
- `lst`: an empty lst that will be built as an single option
- `i`: the index the recursion will run with
- *`final`: the final list of lists that will be built

1 and 0 in the original list have to remain unchanged and -1 has to be changed to 0 or a 1. 
i have to return a list of list with representing all the options that can be assembled from the original list
here are some examples -

```
 input: `[-1,1,1,-1,1]`
output: `[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]]`

input:`[-1,-1,-1]`
output:`[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]`

input:`[0,-1,-1]`
output: `[[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]`
```

this code does work for situations like [-1,-1,-1] but does not work for input like the first expample. it chnages 0 and 1 from the original list but it shouldnt

```
 BLACK = 1
 WHITE = 0
 UNKNOWN = -1


    def row_helper(row, lst, i, final):
    if len(lst) == len(row):
        copied = copy.deepcopy(lst)
        final.append(copied)
        return
    if row[i] == BLACK or row[i] == WHITE:
        lst.append(row[i])
        row_helper(row, lst, i + 1, final)
    else:
        lst.append(BLACK)
        row_helper(row,  lst, i + 1, final)
        lst.pop()
        lst.append(WHITE)
        row_helper(row,  lst, i + 1, final)
        lst.pop()

final1 = []
j = 0
lst2 = []
row1 = [1, 0, -1, -1]
row_helper(row1,lst2, j, final1)
```

i tried replacing the list editing with tuple and than converting to a list later and this code does work for every situation but im trying to figure out how to fix the first code without using tuples
this is the one that work:

```
def row_helper(row, temp_tup, i, valid_options):
    if i == len(row):
        painted_row = [block for block in temp_tup]
        valid_options.append(painted_row)
        return
    if row[i] == BLACK or row[i] == WHITE:
        temp_tup = temp_tup + (row[i],)
        row_helper(row,  temp_tup, i + 1, valid_options)
    else:
        temp_tup = temp_tup + (BLACK,)
        row_helper(row,  temp_tup, i + 1, valid_options)
        temp_tup = temp_tup[:-1]
        temp_tup = temp_tup + (WHITE,)
        row_helper(row,  temp_tup, i + 1, valid_options)


final1 = []
j = 0
lst2 = tuple()
row1 = [0,-1,-1]
row_helper(row1, lst2, j, final1)
print(final1)
```

help would be greatly appriciated

Comment: This could use some editing to A) fix grammar mistakes and B) more importantly, make it clearer exactly what the question is.  Looks like two different questions are being asked here and each is vague as to what the problem has been in achieving the desired result with the code that was posted.  Also, should this be tagged with game-theory?

Comment: edited a bit, hope its clearer